# How do I count within nested resourced and display the results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count

I am building a job board in rails based on PostgreSQL. I want to count and display the amount of job offers per employer on the index of the employer page. What is the code for this kind of count?

I created a nested resource, and associated my employer and offer model, by:

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offers, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `counter_cache` i.e. adding an extra column(offer_count) in employer table & update the counter while making entry in offer table. For more details , check counter_cache in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Your migration should like

```
 def change
    add_column :employers, :offers_count, :integer, default: 0
    Employer.reset_column_information
    Employer.all.each do |p|
      Employer.update_counters p.id, :offers_count => p.offers.length
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I then write a command to fetch the data? 

So if I understand well I should to the following: 
1) 

class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employer, counter_cache: true
end
class Employer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :offers
end

2) Add column offers_count to the employer model. 
3) Rake db:migrate

4) How do I then write a command to fetch the data?

Comment: Simple.. Employer.first.offer_count